# Why forwarding reference does not work?

Tags: c++11, forwarding-reference

I have problem with this piece of code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

struct A{
    template<class UT>
    A(UT &&s) : internal(std::forward<std::string>(s)){

    }

    std::string internal;
};

int main(){
    const std::string &s = "hello";

    A a1{ s };

    std::cout << "s = " << s << std::endl;
}
```

This current example does not compiles and if I change `s` to be non const, it moves the string.

I have similar codes that works OK, but in this case there is something wrong I can not see.

Comment: The term "universal reference" is no longer preferred for this concept, as it is quite a misnomer. Even the inventor of the term has disowned it, preferring instead "forwarding reference".

Comment: Use `std::forward<UT>(s)`, it still won't move the string as it is right now, but at least it compiles then and handles other cases correctly

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki - yep. i am so stupid :D

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: It *shouldn't* move the string. You cannot move from a `const&`.

Comment: @NicolBolas read once again, I said *"it still won't move the string as it is right now"*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a forwarding reference incorrectly. You don't give `std::forward` the destination type. You give it the template it deduced:

```
A(UT &&s) : internal(std::forward<UT>(s)){
```